# Why does my firebase cloud function run multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have written a cloud function for firebase admin. It is to reset a user's password. It passes in the user UID and the new pass, but when I run the function, it not only resets that user's password, it makes that the password for **every** user. Every single user in the database.

Here is the code that calls the function:

```
resetForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let newPass = resetForm['reset-password'].value;
        const resetPasswordFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('resetPassword');
        resetPasswordFunction({docId: docId, newPass: newPass}).then(() => {
            const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-reset');
          M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
          resetForm.reset();
        });
    });
```

and here is the function:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./troop-30-elections-web-app-firebase-adminsdk-obsmr-61cc4bb59e.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://troop-30-elections-web-app.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.resetPassword = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
  return admin.auth().updateUser(data.docId, { 
    password: data.newPass
   })
  .then(() => {
      return {"text": "User Password Successfully Updated"};  // this is what gets sent back to the app
  });
});
```

Comment: What happens when you print the userRecord (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user), do you see the UID of the record you sent to update, or a different one (the last one that was updated)

Comment: I figured it out. It is fixed.

Comment: If you don't mind sharing what was happening as an answer just in case any other person has a similar issue, it would be great